# wp attempt focus, disabling without touching core

Tags: php, javascript

So i've added an extra field to the login form. I have used js to place it at the top. However, whatever I do I don't seem to be able to change the tabindex(or start focus for that matter.

Is there a way to disable wp_attempt_focus so my newly added field get's entered first?

I've tried `tabindex` & `jquery select/focus`

This is the code I have used to get the extra field in

```
<p id="toTheTop">
        <label for="klantnr">Klantnummer<br>
        <input type="text" size="10" value="<?php echo $klantnr; ?>" class="input" id="klantnr" tabindex="1" maxlength="10" name="klantnr" autocomplete="off"></label>
        </p>

        <script>
            (function ( form ) {
                form.insertBefore( document.getElementById( "toTheTop" ), form.childNodes[0] )
            })( document.getElementById( "loginform" ) );
        </script>
```